# Streaming with Amazon S3

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My website (developed with ASP.NET) publishes news along with related JPEG files and flash videos. Right now it is hosted as dedicated server. But it is becoming hard to maintain backup and bandwidth.

Can I host image files, video files and audio files in S3 bucket to resolve my issue? I have seen some articles related to this. But wanted to check with those who already doing this well. Do I need to take care of any steps to do so?

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, S3 works just fine for this. You need to make your buckets public to do so.

Alternatively, you can use CloudFront on top of S3 - http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/. It's a bit more expensive, but I've had good success with it.